# Sort items with different criteria in jQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have this html

```
<ul id="theList">
<li><span class="to-date" date-fromdate ="2014-12"     data-todate="2015-01">2015-01</span></li>
<li><span class="to-date" date-fromdate ="2016-12"      data-todate="2017-01">2017-01</span></li>
<li><span class="to-date" date-fromdate ="2014-12"  data-todate="now">now</span></li>
  <li><span class="to-date" date-fromdate ="2015-01"  data-todate="now">now</span></li>
</ul>
```

And the current JavaScript

```
function sortList(list) {
var $list = $(list);
var elems = $.makeArray($list.find("li"));
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    var $aStr = $(a).find(".to-date").attr("data-todate");
    var $bStr = $(b).find(".to-date").attr("data-todate");

    var $aStrFrom = $(a).find(".to-date").attr("data-fromdate");
    var $bStrFrom = $(b).find(".to-date").attr("data-fromdate");


    if ($aStr != 'now') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return new Date($aStr) < new Date($bStr);
    }
});

$list.html(elems);
}
sortList("#theList");
```

What I want to achieve is that when an items has "now" in the todate attr they are sorted by fromdate attr and placed in top of the the list. Items that dosent have "now" in the todate attr are sorted by todate in the bottom of the list.

How is that possible?

Here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/x1z47m0j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison function passed to [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) should return an integer, not a boolean. In short, `comparator(a, b)` should return 1 if `a > b`, -1 if `a < b` and 0 in case of equality.

Also, you're ending up doing `new Date('now')` for certain values of `b`, which yields invalid dates. You do not want messing with those.

A good comparison function is all you need to reproduce the desired ordering, as long as you're careful to cover all possible cases for `a, b` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7mhw596u/1/)) :

```
if ($aStr == 'now') {
    if ($bStr == 'now')
        return -comparator(new Date($aStrFrom), new Date($bStrFrom));
    else
        return -1;
} else if ($bStr == 'now') {
    return 1;
} else {
    return comparator(new Date($aStr), new Date($bStr));
}

function comparator(a, b) {
    return a > b ? 1 : (a == b ? 0 : -1);
}
```

Comment: If I reverse the comparison so I should get the newest first it still displays the oldest "now" first

Comment: Corrected the answer, `new Date(...) < new Date(...)` returns a boolean, silly me :) now you have a sort-compatible `comparator` function, you just negate it to get the reverse ordering. Also, I corrected a small typo in your markup (`date-fromdate` should be `data-fromdate`).

Answer (score 0):

I would treat them as 2 sort lists.

If you filter and sort the `now` and append that group then do same procedure for the others they end up with 2 distinct sorts.

```
// create one sorting utility plugin
$.fn.sortDates= function (dateType) {
    return this.sort(function (a, b) {
        var aString = $(a).find(".to-date").data(dateType);
        var bString = $(b).find(".to-date").data(dateType);
        return new Date(aString) > new Date(bString);
    });
};

function sortList(list) {
    var $list = $(list);
    var elems = $list.find("li");
    // filter into 2 groups
    var $now = elems.filter(function () {
        return $(this).find('.to-date').data('todate') === 'now';
    });
    var $other = elems.filter(function () {
        return $(this).find('.to-date').data('todate') !== 'now';
    });
    //sort and append each group
    $now.sortDates('fromdate').appendTo($list);

    $other.sortDates("todate").appendTo($list);

}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/x1z47m0j/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: How do I reverse the order so the newest is sorted first in the fromdate ?

Comment: I didn't notice that you were using `date` in one attribute and `data` in another. Also should parse strings to really get proper date constructor...see: https://jsfiddle.net/x1z47m0j/8/

Comment: Sorry about the mistake with the data attr. Good example you made

Answer (score 0):

One sort only method ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1z47m0j/7/)) - see comments:

```
function sortList(list) {
    var $list = $(list);
    var elems = $.makeArray($list.find("li"));
    elems.sort(function (a, b) {
        var $aStr = $(a).find(".to-date").attr("data-todate");
        var $bStr = $(b).find(".to-date").attr("data-todate");

        var $aStrFrom = $(a).find(".to-date").attr('date-fromdate');
        var $bStrFrom = $(b).find(".to-date").attr('date-fromdate');

        if($aStr === 'now' && $bStr === 'now') { // if both have now - sort by from-date
           return new Date($bStrFrom).getTime() - new Date($aStrFrom).getTime(); // reverse to change sort order
        }

        if($aStr === 'now') {
            return -1; // if first have now return -1
        }

        if($bStr === 'now') {
            return 1; // if second have now return 1
        }

        return new Date($bStr).getTime() - new Date($aStr).getTime(); // if both lack now sort by to-date - reverse to change sort order
    });

    $list.html(elems);
}
sortList("#theList");
```